# Removing php url won't work on my XAMPP localhost but will work on server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

Using the following code to remove php from URLS, works on my online server, but will not work in XAMPP local host

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ $1.php [L]
```

I've tried changing AllowOverride to all in httpd.conf file and changing other settings in conf files but can not figure out what's preventing it

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have turned on **mod_rewrite** in your xampp (it can be turned on in your online server by default).

Here you can check how to do it: https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp-wamp/